# How do I fix Node 17792 ExtensionLoadWarning?

Tags: node.js

`(node:17792) ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\xxxxxxx\extensions\fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi: Unrecognized manifest key 'browser_action'. Unrecognized manifest key 'minimum_chrome_version'. Unrecognized manifest key 'update_url'. Cannot load extension with file or directory name _metadata. Filenames starting with "_" are reserved for use by the system.`

I'm creating an electron-react app on Windows 10 and receiving this error.

Relatively new to programming.

Does anyone know how to fix this error without breaking changes ?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are using a version of Google Chrome that is compatible with the extension. The **minimum_chrome_version** key in the manifest file specifies the minimum version of Chrome required for the extension to work.

Or you can go with few steps to address this issue:

**Check Extension Manifest:**
Open the extension's manifest file (manifest.json) and make sure that the keys mentioned in the warning are correctly spelled and formatted. Ensure that there are no typos or syntax errors.

**Extension Compatibility:**
Verify that the extension is compatible with the version of Chrome you are using. The minimum_chrome_version key specifies the minimum version of Chrome required for the extension to work. Make sure it's set appropriately.

**Metadata Directory:**
The warning also mentions a directory or file named *metadata. Filenames starting with "*" are reserved, so there might be an issue with this directory. Check its contents and make sure it adheres to Chrome's extension structure.

**Extension Update:**
Check if there is an updated version of the extension available. It's possible that the version you have is outdated or has a known issue that has been fixed in a later release.

**Reinstall Extension:**
If none of the above steps resolve the issue, you might consider uninstalling the extension and reinstalling it. Ensure that you download the extension from a reputable source.